# Sceneform: how does Node.setLookDirection work?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, arcore, sceneform

I am trying to figure out how Node.setLookDirection works but I didn't manage even after many simple tests.

Here is my code:

```
MaterialFactory.makeOpaqueWithColor(context, new Color(android.graphics.Color.DKGRAY))
            .thenAccept(
                    material -> {
                        ModelRenderable cylRenderable =
                                ShapeFactory.makeCylinder(radius, height, Vector3.zero(), material);

                        Node newNode = new Node();
                        newNode.setRenderable(cylRenderable);
                        newNode.setLocalPosition(position);

                        Vector3 lookDirection = new Vector3(1,1,1);
                        newNode.setLookDirection(lookDirection);

                        rootNode.addChild(newNode);
                    }
            );
```

The lookDirection is not at all what I expect. I can try simple directions like (1,0,0) or (0,1,0) ; the same, I don't understand the result.

May somebody explain how this setLookDirection method works ? With an example + drawing if possible.

Thanks !